# How Gmail app gets info about new email?

Tags: java, android, gmail

How Gmail knows that some new emails are on server? Does it use GCM?

I wondering about it, because I also want to implement this king of functionality in my app. Can you give me some points to start with this?

Comment: For a start, have a look at [Push technology @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

Comment: yes GCM is exactly what it uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Gmail does use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to get push notifications of new emails. The [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) guide is a good place to start, although there are quite a few steps in setting up both the [client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) (i.e., the Android side) and the [server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) component.